# Angular 4 view nor updated from service

Tags: angular

I'm struggling with issue that my view is not updated from service.

What I'm trying to achieve is message handling. I send message to service and subscribed component gets updated. On model, everything works perfectly, but view is not changing at all.

My service:

```
import {Injectable} from '@angular/core';
import {Observer} from 'rxjs/Observer';
import {Subscription} from 'rxjs/Subscription';
import {Subject} from 'rxjs/Rx';

import {MyMessage} from './myMessage';

@Injectable()
export class MessageHandlingService {
    private _message: Subject<MyMessage> = new Subject();

    handle(message: string, stack: string) {
        // console.log('handle', message, stack);
        let newMyMessage: MyMessage;

        if (stack) {
            newMyMessage = new MyMessage(2, message, stack);
        } else {
            newMyMessage = new MyMessage(1, message, stack);
        }

        this._message.next(newMyMessage);
    }

    subscribeMessages(observer: Observer<MyMessage>): Subscription {
        // console.log('MessageHandling - subscriber accepted');
        return this._message.subscribe(observer);
    }
}
```

My component:

```
import {Component, OnInit, OnDestroy} from '@angular/core';
import {Observer} from 'rxjs/Observer';
import {Subscription} from 'rxjs/Subscription';

import {MessageHandlingService} from './messageHandling.service';
import {MyMessage} from './myMessage';

@Component({
    templateUrl: './my-messager.component.html',
    selector: 'mymy-messager'
})
export class MyMessagerComponent implements OnInit, OnDestroy, Observer<MyMessage> {

    private _subscription: Subscription;

    display: boolean = false;

    msg: MyMessage = null;

    constructor(private messageHandling: MessageHandlingService) {}

    ngOnInit() {
        console.log('MyMessager is subscribing');
        this._subscription = this.messageHandling.subscribeMessages(this);
    }

    ngOnDestroy() {
        console.log('MyMessager is UN-subscribing');
        if (this._subscription) {
            this._subscription.unsubscribe();
        }
    }

    /* istanbul ignore next */
    complete() {}

    /* istanbul ignore next */
    error(e: any) {
        if (console) {
            console.error(e);
        }
    }

    next(message: MyMessage) {
        console.log('observed next', message);
        this._showMessage(message);
    }

    private _showMessage(message: MyMessage) {
        this.msg = message;
        console.log('Settind display to true')
        this.display = true;
    }

    hideDialog() {
        this.msg = null;
        this.display = false;
    }
}
```

and component HTML

```
{{msg}}
{{display}}
<span *ngIf="msg">
    <span *ngIf="msg.severity === 1">
        <p-dialog 
            header="Information message"
            [(visible)]="display" 
            modal="modal"
            showEffect="fade">
            <p>{{msg.message}}</p>
            <footer>
                <div
                    class="ui-dialog-buttonpane ui-widget-content ui-helper-clearfix">
                    <button type="button" pButton icon="fa-close" (click)="hideDialog()" label="OK"></button>
                </div>
            </footer> 
        </p-dialog>
    </span>
    <span *ngIf="msg.severity === 2">
        <p-dialog 
            header="Technical message"
            [(visible)]="display" 
            modal="modal"
            showEffect="fade">
            <p>{{msg.message}}</p>
            <br />
            <hr />
            <p style="white-space: pre;">{{msg.stackTrace}}</p>
            <footer>
                <div
                    class="ui-dialog-buttonpane ui-widget-content ui-helper-clearfix">
                    <button type="button" pButton icon="fa-close" (click)="hideDialog()" label="OK"></button>
                </div>
            </footer> 
        </p-dialog>
    </span>
</span>
```

I have tried

```
ChangeDetectorRef.detectChanges()
```

and

```
ChangeDetectorRef.markForCheck()
```

and

```
ApplicationRef.tick()
```

and even

```
NgZone run
```

but no luck. Same code worked for Angular 2.

Comment: What binding do you expect to get updated from what code?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

During `this._message.subscribe(observer);` execution SafeSubscriber is being created

```
function SafeSubscriber(_parentSubscriber, observerOrNext, error, complete) {
    _super.call(this);
    this._parentSubscriber = _parentSubscriber;
    var next;
    var context = this;
    if (isFunction_1.isFunction(observerOrNext)) {
        next = observerOrNext;
    }
    else if (observerOrNext) {
        next = observerOrNext.next;
        error = observerOrNext.error;
        complete = observerOrNext.complete;
        if (observerOrNext !== Observer_1.empty) {
            context = Object.create(observerOrNext); // this line
```

So you lost the link to the current `AppComponent` instance

[image]

[image]

For instance, this should work for you

```
subscribeMessages(observer: Observer<MyMessage>): Subscription {
  const subscriber = new Subscriber(
      observer.next.bind(observer),
      observer.error.bind(observer),
      observer.complete.bind(observer))

  return this._message.subscribe(subscriber);
}
```

or you can use object like

```
const subscriber = {
   next: observer.next.bind(observer),
   error: observer.error.bind(observer),
   complete: observer.complete.bind(observer))
}
```

**[Plunker Example](https://plnkr.co/edit/sEmO1J5iTTAtjd13HTbg?p=preview)**

Answer (score 1):

It's a `this` binding problem. Your code works fine if you replace

```
    this.messageHandling.subscribeMessages(this);
```

by

```
    this.messageHandling.subscribeMessages({
      next: (message) => this.next(message),
      error: (error) => this.complete(error),
      complete: () => this.complete()
    });
```

See [a demo](http://plnkr.co/edit/YQZHfy0XHcH9JYk5AnQz?p=info).

That said, instead of having your service expose a method that takes an Observer as argument, I'd rather expose the observable instead. That way, the caller can easily add the operators it wants before actually subscribing to the observable. [Demo](http://plnkr.co/edit/1cubYgbtvgMvjoeUCIZt?p=preview).